# All possible combinations of dictionary values given input string. Python

Tags: python, dictionary, combinations, python-itertools

I'm trying to get all possible strings from the values in a dictionary given a particular key.  For example, 'A' could mean either 'aaa','aba', or 'aac' and 'B' could mean either 'bbb','bab', or 'bbc', etc.

I've given an example of the output where it shows most combinations of the possible strings

```
import itertools
in_ = 'ABC'
D = {'A':['aaa','aba','aac'],'B':['bbb','bab','bbc'],'C':['ccc','cac','ccb']}

#out_ = ['aaabbbccc','ababbbccc','aacbbbccc','aaababccc','aaabbcccc','aaabbbcac','aaabbbccb'...]
```

I started writing the code but it started to get REALLY messy and I feel that there is a way to use itertools or something more pythonic to achieve this goal

```
output = []
for char in in_:
    out_string = ''
    while char:
        for v in D[char]:
            while v:
                for char2 in in_:
                    out_string
#not pythonic . . .
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you've got `itertools` imported there. Let's use it! We want to take the Cartesian product `D['A'] × D['B'] × D['C']`, so we'll do precisely that using `itertools.product`.

```
import itertools

in_ = 'ABC'
D = {'A':['aaa','aba','aac'],'B':['bbb','bab','bbc'],'C':['ccc','cac','ccb']}

iterables = [D[character] for character in in_]
out_ = [''.join(tup) for tup in itertools.product(*iterables)]
```

Now, `out_` is:

```
['aaabbbccc', 'aaabbbcac', 'aaabbbccb', 'aaababccc', 'aaababcac', 'aaababccb', 
 'aaabbcccc', 'aaabbccac', 'aaabbcccb', 'ababbbccc', 'ababbbcac', 'ababbbccb', 
 'abababccc', 'abababcac', 'abababccb', 'ababbcccc', 'ababbccac', 'ababbcccb', 
 'aacbbbccc', 'aacbbbcac', 'aacbbbccb', 'aacbabccc', 'aacbabcac', 'aacbabccb', 
 'aacbbcccc', 'aacbbccac', 'aacbbcccb']
```

Is that the result you were going for?

Comment: incredible, thank you so much! I knew itertools was the way to go but i dind't know that product could give that result.

Comment: what does the *iterables do to iterables?

Comment: The `*` is [an unpacking operator](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). So `product(*iterables)` is equivalent to `product(iterables[0], iterables[1], ...)` except you don't need to know in advance how many elements `iterables` has.

Comment: Is there anyway to turn it into a generator so it doesn't use up as much space?

Comment: `itertools.product` already returns an iterator, so all you need to do to make `out_` a generator is replace the square brackets `[]` for a list comprehension with `()` for a generator comprehension.